# How to use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer to find every user's top tags?

Tags: sql, dataexplorer

I use this query in [the Stack Exchange *Data Explorer*](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/):

```
select id, reputation
from users
where reputation >300000
```

What should I add to this query in order to have an additional column with the "best" tag of the user?

That is the tag where the user has the highest score and/or the user has the most posts (questions, answers).
For example, in my user page, in top tags, I can see [r](/questions/tagged/r).

Comment: Do you mean one of the tags as [defined at this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118956/what-defines-a-top-tag)? Or, do you mean just the tag that the user scores the highest at?

Comment: @BrockAdams just the tag the use has the highest score the user has the most posts (questions, answers).  For example for me in user page in top tags I can see r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using [Common Table Expressions (CTE's)](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/) and [Correlated Subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery).

See it in SEDE at: [data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/815284/...](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/815284/top-tags-for-users-over-300k-reputation)

```sql
WITH tagAndUserStats AS (
    SELECT
                t.tagname,
                p.owneruserid       AS userid,
                SUM (p.score)       AS tagScore,
                COUNT (p.id)        AS postCount
    FROM        posts       p
    INNER JOIN  posttags    pt      ON pt.postid = COALESCE (p.parentid, p.id)
    INNER JOIN  tags        t       ON pt.tagid = t.id
    WHERE       p.owneruserid >= 1
    AND         p.posttypeid IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY    t.tagname,
                p.owneruserid
)
SELECT
            u.id as [User Link],
            u.Reputation,
            (   SELECT TOP 1    tu.tagname
                FROM            tagAndUserStats tu
                WHERE           tu.userid = u.id
                ORDER BY        tu.tagScore DESC
            ) AS [Top Tag by Score],
            (   SELECT TOP 1    tu.tagname
                FROM            tagAndUserStats tu
                WHERE           tu.userid = u.id
                ORDER BY        tu.postCount DESC
            ) AS [Top Tag by Posts]
FROM        users u
WHERE       u.reputation > 300000
ORDER BY    u.reputation DESC
```

Which returns results like:

```
User Link       Reputation   Top Tag by Score   Top Tag by Posts
Jon Skeet         1010838            c#                 c#
BalusC             784437          java                jsf
Darin Dimitrov     783553            c#                 c#
VonC               753855           git                git
```

---

**Notes:**

1. Reference [the SEDE schema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede).
2. Because you specified both questions and answers, and didn't exclude *community wiki* posts, this query's results will sometimes be off from what the customary values are.
   For badges and whatnot, question-posts and question-scores don't count, only answers do.